# Find item if exist in deep nested children array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find if item exist in deep nested array.

**Example :**

```
let arr = [
  {
   id: 1 ,
   title : 'Test' ,
   children: 
  [
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' , hasChild : true },
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' , hasChild : false },
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' },
  ] 
 },
]
```

I need to looping thought `arr.children` and trying to find if it has a property with name **hasChild** find item and set it on false.

After looping I need to get an array like **:**

```
let arr = [
  {
   id: 1 ,
   title : 'Test' ,
   children: 
  [
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' , hasChild : false }, //here is changed hasChild to false
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' , hasChild : false },
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' },
  ] 
 },
]
```

I am find way but i need better solution :

```
    arr.map(it) => {
      if (it.hasChild) {
        it.dashCheck = false; 
      }
    });
```

Comment: I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive functions to make operations on inifitely nested objects/arrays etc.

```
function recursiveUpdate(array, index) {
  const element = array[index];
  if(!element) return;
  if(Object.keys(element).indexOf('children') > -1) {
    element.hasChild = true;
    recursiveUpdate(element['children'], 0);
  } else {
    element.hasChild = false;
    recursiveUpdate(array, index+1);
  }
}

recursiveUpdate(arr, 0);
```

Comment: what is 0 index? why 0

Comment: @Gardioslast this function is checking each index of the given array (your array in this case), 0 is the starting index as it should be. Function will process through all the indexes of the array, it will increase the index by 1 when the object residing at that index has no children.

Comment: Nice but this function no work :/

Comment: Could you share a jsfiddle code with me?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Seems like the question was altered after I gave my answer. Updated my answer to reflect this.

If the structure of `arr` is always like the one you mentioned in your question, you could simple iterate over the `children` by using the `forEach` method of the `Array` class:

```js
arr.forEach(item => {
  item.children.forEach(child => {
    // Edit: Revised solution 
    if (child.hasChild === true) {
      child.hasChild = false;
    }
    // Edit: Previous solution
    // child.hasChild = child.hasChild === true ? false : child.hasChild;
  });
});
```

**Note**: This will alter the original array and not create a copy with the altered value for `hasChild`.

Comment: This will not work as this is going to add `hasChild` property with `undefined` in the object which does not contain this property.

Comment: @CreativeLearner You are right, maybe the question was editd after I gave my answer?! Anyway, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo :**

```js
let arr = [{
  id: 1 ,
  title : 'Test' ,
  children: 
  [
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' , hasChild : true },
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' , hasChild : false },
    {id: 1 , title: 'Title' },
  ] 
}];

arr.forEach((obj) => {
    obj.children.forEach((childObj) => {
    if (childObj.hasChild) {
        childObj.hasChild = false;
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```